# How to solve "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"

Tags: json, curl, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF with simple-JWT for authentication. When I log in using the browsable API, everything works fine, but when I make a `CURL` POST request for login using:

```bash
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"email":"anyone@gmail.com", "password":"Sajeyks254"}" http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
```

I get the error below:

```bash
{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Try to use single quite to specify request payload: `'{"email":"anyone@gmail.com", "password":"Sajeyks254"}'`

Comment: This did not work..